# insert html in div inside of iframe js

Tags: jquery, iframe, inserthtml

```
 <script> 

jQuery("iframe").load(function() {

 console.log('can you hear me?');

 $('iframe').contents().find('#findme').html('lorium ipsom');  

});

 </script>
```

I am having trouble getting this to work. I am trying to find a div inside of an iframe (on the same server) and then inject some html in there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, sorry. But since it's on your server, can'T you modify the file itself?

Answer (score 0):

The source inside of iframes are 'protected' from outside modification. This helps to prevent XSS (cross site scripting) attacks. What you're wanting semi-violates the same-origin policy.

The only way to make it happen is to add the javascript to the document inside the iframe itself.

Comment: are you sure??? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)